# What does a "timing push" mean

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology, starcraft

I've heard this term used many-a-time in StarCraft 2 (and 1) replays on the web.  At first, I always assumed it meant the player was sending out an attack force at a specific time in the game that's considered a good time to push out, or inside what is considered to be an optimal window of attack.

But the more videos I watched the term seems to be used when the player is just attacking, regardless of when/why/how, and about the scenario in which it isn't used is when a player counter-attacks after successfully defending another players timing push (and then they just call it counter-attack).

So why do they call it timing push? And not just "attacking".  Or is it in fact only (properly) used at certain "times" during the game?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A timing push involves making an attack at a certain point in your build order, such that the attack coincides with the completion of a researched upgrade, or a certain mass of units.

For example: you might see a Terran Bio timing push, where the Terran player moves his forces out such that Stimpack technology will have *just* finished as they reach the enemy forces.

Also applies to Weapon / Armor upgrades. Since the Weapon / Armor upgrades *often* completely cancel each other out, it's best to start fights when *you* have the upgrade, and your opponent does not. If you wait too long, your opponent (if they know what they're doing) will complete their own counter-research, and your advantage will be lost.

Hence, timing push; Timing an attack such that it occurs when you have the momentary advantage.

Comment: that makes sense.  I have a feeling some of the vids I've watched the commentators didn't understand the term, or didn't give it context (just saying "timing push" instead of "his first medics have hit the field, so he's doing his timing push), hence the confusion

Comment: For clarity purposes the Terran Bio timing push usually refers to the +1 Bio push (the +1 here referring to +1 damage).  Stim should actually be finished before this.

Comment: +1 bio timing push is actually a hold over from SC1 where the build order was extremely polished.  SC2 hasn't been around long enough for that level of polish.

Answer (score 2):

There are times where certain races are succeptable to certain tactics for brief intervals. Regardless of what they do.

For example. A fast Terran player can get a couple of marauders in an enemy base before they have time for the proper counter. It's really only a few seconds, but it's enough to cause some damage, and it may put them at a disadvantage later.

But If the defending player doesn't counter it at all, then it can be devastating.

Source [BlizzCast 14]

Comment: I would not refer to BlizzCast as a resource for pro Starcraft information anymore than I would refer to the Nike podcast for information on Tiger Woods.